# Downloading to bibtex faster

Tags: bibtex, automation, jabref

Since this is latex specific:

Is there an automated way to download bibtex formats from pages such as ACM, IEEE, google scholar etc? The whole process seems time consuming from getting to the page, then finding where the "download citation" is, then choosing bibtex, then copy paste, then enter to JabRef, then update with the pdf (optional).

Comment: You forgot an important point in your list "manually check if this automatically generated bib entry contains correct information".

Comment: Alternatively, [JabRef's help page](http://help.jabref.org/en/#fetching-entries-from-the-web) indicates support for searching and citing items in ACM, IEEE, Google Scholar, and others. I assume that's slightly more automated than your procedure.

Comment: @samcarter Is it very common for these sites to have false data?

Comment: @AnnaK. Too often to blindly rely on these entries. In most cases these data bases are automatically filled, during which all kinds of things can go wrong. Most common problems are confusions of names consisting of multiple parts or wrong classification of the work, i.e. a proceeding which is exported as a article etc. -- and surprisingly often I saw wrong years.

Comment: Or wrong pagination seems common, too.

Comment: This question is about reference management and therefore off-topic. Perhaps you might want to ask this on [Academia.SX](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have also a look at JabFox, an add-on for.JabRef which helps with the process

Comment: @ChristophS That's the answer I was looking for. I could accept it as an (official) answer if it was possible.